# Handle duplicate data in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

**Problem description:**

when the data are received to the source_table the update policy in kusto is run to store the data in end_point_table.
the update function should handle the duplication data and store just the new data inside the end_point_table. that mean that if we got data form the source_table which are the same what we have in the end_point_table then no data will store.

**what i did:**

the end_point_table have already data

```
.ingest inline into table end_point_table <|
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,property,128
```

i have a source table called source_table, which i ingest the data to it like the following

```
.ingest inline into table source_table <|
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,128

.ingest inline into table source_table <|
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,property,128
```

the following function will triggered automatically

```
let _incoming =(
            source_table
            | where property == "property"
            | project device_id, timestamp, value
            | distinct *
        );
let _old_data = (
            end_point_table
        );

_incoming
        | join kind = leftouter(
            _old_data
            | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by device_id
        ) on device_id
        | where ( 
            timestamp != timestamp1
            or value != value1
        )
        | project device_id, timestamp, value
```

result:
when i query the data after the ingestion i got three row instead of one like this

```
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,property,128
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,property,128
1,2020-01-01T12:00:00Z,property,128
```

**the question is:**

is there any solution to avoid ingestion the duplicated data in the end_point_table. or did i used the update policy wrongly

Answer (score 0):

Update policies is not the right approach for this.

There are multiple correct approaches to handle dedup, please read about them here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates

Comment: offcourse i checked the documentation before i post the question.

Comment: Can you please explain why none of the approaches described there worked for you, and you're looking for another solution?